# Life time of icon handles return from ExtractIconEx

Tags: winapi, icons

I'm using [`ExtractIconEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648069(v=vs.85).aspx) to extract icons handles (and later use them):

```
ExtractIconEx("c:\\progra~1\\winzip\\winzip32.exe", 0, &hIconLarge, &hIconSmall, 1);
```

I store the handles in an object and later use the icons handles with `DrawIcon`. when the object is freed I destroy both handles via `DestroyIcon`.

My question: is it guaranteed both handles are available and owned by my application (for it's entire lifetime), or should I use [`CopyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648058(v=vs.85).aspx) for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to call DestroyIcon().  Tells the OS "I don't need the guarantee anymore".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation of [ExtractIconEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648069.aspx):

> You must destroy all icons extracted by **ExtractIconEx** by calling the [**DestroyIcon**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648063.aspx) function.

This implies, that the lifetime ends, when you call `DestroyIcon`. In other words, you own the icons returned by `ExtractIconEx`.

Comment: "This implies...", that *implication* part was what bothered me.

Comment: @zig: The Windows API provides a plain C interface, so cleanup is explicit. Objects are valid until they are disposed. There really isn't much implied here. It's how resource management is done in a language that doesn't provide any means of automatic garbage collection.